# Removing extra spaces in the output of sql query through shell script

Tags: sql, shell, unix, sh

I've written a sql query that will get some output for me. Below is the code:

```
sqlplus -s user/passwd@DB << EOF > /dev/null 2>&1

set heading off
set feedback off
set verify off
set pagesize 50000
set trimspool on
set wrap off
set linesize 2000

spool /home/sql_test.txt;

select /*+parallel(a,4)*/ substr(dati, 1, 11), substr(dati, 13, 500)
from ferdquatadm.tmp_fq_migration a, account b, customer_node_history c
where substr(dati, 1, 11) = account_name
and b.customer_node_id = c.customer_node_id
and sysdate between effective_start_date and effective_end_date
and schedule_id = 1234;

spool off;

exit
EOF

sed '1d' sql_test.txt > sqltest_1.txt
mv sqltest_1.txt my_code_123.txt
rm -rf sql_test.txt
```

But I want the output like below:

```
23554400043     0117601738;22TU003719388001V;
23554402883     0823973229;TTT0823973229001C;
23554402950     024071080;MNT024071080001D;
23554405827     0415260614;TL20415260614001R;
23554405828     08119270800;TL2U003010407001G;
23554406553     011306895;VBT011306895001E;
23554406557     054121509;TL2054121509001M;
```

The output I'm getting is like below:

```
23554402243                       0584940772;2TZ0584940772001U;
23554402272                       0423721840;7TT0423721840001B;
23554402303                       0110770863;BBTU500248822001Q;
23554402305                       02311301;BTB02311301001J;
23554402563                       0550503408;PPTU004984208001O;
23554402605                       0457553223;Q0T0457553223001I;
```

I want to remove the extra spaces between two columns in my output.

Comment: What is the size of the dati field?

Comment: dati field holds a record of around 50k rows in the sql query.